# How to dynamically create static method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If I have this:

```
class Math {
  static add(a, b) {
    return a + b
  }
}
```

and I want turn it into:

```
class Math {
  static add(a, b) {
    return a + b
  }
  static subtract(a, b) {
    return a - b
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do it dynamically? eg.

```
class Math {
  static add(a, b) {
    return a+b
  }
}

Math.extend({
  subtract: function(a, b) {
     return a-b
  }
})

Math.subtract(1,1) // 0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Static methods are nothing but methods on the constructor. So all you need to do is assign the methods to `Math`:

```
Object.assign(Math, {
  subtract(a, b) {
    return a - b
  }
});
```

Comment: Why did you use `Object.assign()` when `Math.subtract = function() {...}` should work just fine?

Comment: Because OP used `Math.extend(...)` making it look like they might want to add more methods, in which case  `Object.assign` might be more useful. But whatever works is fine of course :)

Comment: its a common pattern to use assign for extending prototype as this is the only way to extend it with property accessors.

Comment: accepting this answer cause of the detail about how I preferred an "extend" similar syntax :)

Comment: Actually is there any way to do this in ES6? Object.assign doesn't exist without using a polyfill. Is there any other built in way to do it?

Comment: @kidcapital: `Object.assign` *is* ES6. If you don't want to polyfill APIs then you'd have to assign the property directly or simply create your own function that does the same thing as `Object.assign`.

Comment: @kidcapital - The method in other answers (including my answer) of directly assigning a property to the `Math` object as in `Math.subtract = function(a, b) {...}` works just fine even in ES3, ES4, ES5.  Or you could use `Object.defineProperty()` too in ES5+.  `Object.assign()` just allows you to attach multiple static methods in one function call, but you can just direct assign each method individually without using `Object.assign()` and have wide browser compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Static methods are just methods on the constructor, so you can just define one at any time like this:

```
Math.subtract = function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
}
```

Note: This will work in ANY browser currently in use as it does not rely on any new or recent features.

Comment: Why the downvote?  What's wrong with this method of creating a static method?

Answer (score 1):

When compiling this down to ES5 you essentially get this:

```
function Math() {
}
Math.add = function(a, b) { return a + b; }
```

So following that, you can add a dynamic static method like this:

```
Math.subtract = function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
}
```

Or since you're using ES6, you could use an arrow function:

```
Math.subtract = (a, b) => a - b;
```

Comment: you want the static method's this to point to the class - so the arrow function is not the best idea

Comment: @PeterAronZentai: Good point, I don't think people usually use `this` in static methods. Too confusing with `this` in instance methods.

Comment: thats the only way to see what class was it invoked on - it also inherits down the chain.

Comment: @PeterAronZentai Maybe so but this function doesn't even use any member properties so it's safe to use an arrow function.

Comment: you might be right... I just pinpointed that the fat arrow is not quite equivalent with class methods - as far as the std goes

Comment: @PeterAronZentai: If it's about spec compliance, yo';d also have to use `Object.defineProperty` since methods are not enumerable. Also not sure about `super`...

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to assign the property to the class:

```
class Test {}

Test.method = function() {
    alert("works");
};

Test.method(); // works
```

https://jsfiddle.net/byppz1vt/1/

Answer (score -2):

You can add static methods via `Math.subtract = function() { // code here };`.

Comment: This does not create a `static` method.  This creates an instance method.