# How to break static methods out to their own file and export correctly via ES6?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-class

This question is a follow up [to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53188230/using-es6-class-syntax-how-to-implement-class-methods-from-other-files) which examines how to break apart class files when instance and static methods become large and make a single class file too unwieldy to work with.

That question found a good answer for instance methods, but a good answer for static factory functions still eludes. Consider this ES6 class:

```
const fnCreate = require('./create');
const fnInstanceMethod = require('./instanceMethod');

class Door {
  constructor() {
    this.species = 'Oak';
    this.instanceMethod = fnInstanceMethod; // <-- works great
  }

  // Cannot connect static to required files...
  static create = fnCreate; // Syntax error unexpected '='

  // so static has to be written in class..
  static create() {
    return new Door(); // <-- the only line in fnCreate
  }
}
module.exports = Door; // but it exports and works fine...
```

You can see where it would be super sweet to just require in a static function, but I have not found a way to do so with ES6; it has to be implemented in the class file. **So, question 1 of 2, "Is there a way to require in a factory function and hook it up staticly in ES6 classes?"**

This ES6 "inability" led me to do an ES5 rewrite as follows:

```
const fnCreate = require('./create');
const fnInstanceMethod = require('./instanceMethod');

function Door() {
  this.species = 'Oak';
  this.instanceMethod = fnInstanceMethod; // <-- works great
}

Door.create = fnCreate; // <-- totally solves the file problem; works fine

module.exports = Door; // <-- NOPE! Node says "Door" is not a constructor"
```

This avoids one problem and stepped into another. Under "regular" JS that code works fine and Door.create() returns a new Door object. But the export breaks the implementation somehow, erroring with "Door is not a constructor." **Question 2 of 2, "Can the above ES5 code be exported to work correctly?"**

Comment: I'm not sure about your `"Door" is not a constructor"` error https://jsfiddle.net/9d5xo7ac/ If `fnCreate` is in a separate file, it won't have scope of `Door`, so I would think the error would be `Uncaught ReferenceError: Door is not defined` when `create()` (that is, `fnCreate`) is called

Comment: Possible duplicate of, but at least related to [How to dynamically create static method in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35049091/218196)

Comment: `class`es are more or less just syntactic sugar. `Door` is a function, whether you use `class Door {}` or `function Door() {}`.

Comment: @FelixKling - very helpful link, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an ES6 class, you can assign to the class object and have what is essentially a static method, just like what you'd do in ES5:

```
class Door {
  constructor() {
    this.species = 'Oak';
    this.instanceMethod = fnInstanceMethod; // <-- works great
  }
}
Door.create = fnCreate;
```

Note that your

```
this.instanceMethod = fnInstanceMethod; // <-- works great
```

while it *works*, it's probably not the best idea - if you want to imitate standard inheritence from the prototype (like when separating things out over multiple files isn't needed), you should assign to the prototype object instead, just like in ES5:

```
class Door {
  constructor() {
    this.species = 'Oak';
  }
}
Door.create = fnCreate;
Door.prototype.instanceMethod = fnInstanceMethod;
```

I'm not sure about the "Door is not a constructor" error you're having, but with your current implementation, `fnCreate` (in a separate file) won't have scope of `Door`, so `fnCreate` won't be able to reference and create a `new Door`. One way to solve this would be to export a function that *takes* `Door` as an input, and returns a function that returns an instance:

```
// makeCreate.js
module.exports = theClass => () => new theClass();

// Door.js
const makeCreate = require('./makeCreate');
const fnInstanceMethod = require('./instanceMethod');
class Door {
  constructor() {
    this.species = 'Oak';
  }
}
Door.create = makeCreate(Door);
Door.prototype.instanceMethod = fnInstanceMethod;

module.exports = Door;
```

Or, the `makeCreate` in ES5:

```
function makeCreate(theClass) {
  return function() {
    return new theClass();
  }
}
module.exports = makeCreate;
```

Comment: I just tested this out and yes! it works. **Did not think ES5 and ES6 could be mixed that way**. And the module.exports works fine as well. Would you please edit your code to include the `module.exports = Door;` so that we leave a complete answer in our wake? Thanks!

Comment: your nested arrow function line ( `module.exports = theClass => () => new theClass();` ) is some _serious_ ES6 dark arts lol. Could you unpack that a bit? Maybe an ES5 rewrite to help understanding?

Comment: See edit, though it adds a lot of extra syntax noise IMO

Comment: completely agree, love arrow functions, but the nested nature of that gem is not apparent IMO even after some study. I appreciate your time.